# Why the CMD/Cygwin shell does not return after WinExec?

Tags: delphi, shell, console, cygwin, windows-shell

The Delphi console application in question tries to utilize `WinExec` to call `Cygwin`'s `echo.exe` to output with color. `Cygwin` is installed under `C:\cygwin`. Its `echo.exe` is `C:\cygwin\bin\echo.exe`.

The reason to choose `WinExec` over `ShellExecute` is `ShellExecute` will instantiate a new shell and echo the texts in that new shell.

The same behavior occurs when I invoke the console application within Windows' CMD shell.

### First attempt

[image: picture of the first attempt]

As shown in the picture, the shell does not return to the prompt. I though WinExec does not finish or need another carriage.

```
program TestConsole;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Windows;

begin
  WinExec('C:\cygwin\bin\echo.exe -e "\e[1;34mColored text.\e[0m"', SW_NORMAL);
end.
```

### Second attempt

[image: picture of the second attempt]

As shown in the picture, it is clear that WinExec already finish. But the shell still does not return to the prompt. I am confused about the reason. Could you help to comment? Any comment will be appreciated!!

```
program TestConsole;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Windows;

var
  I: Integer;
begin
  I := WinExec('C:\cygwin\bin\echo.exe -e "\e[1;34mColored text.\e[0m"', SW_NORMAL);
  Writeln(IntToStr(I));
end.
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using Cygwin's `echo` to do output from a Windows system call (`WinExec`) in a Windows console application? Have you looked at the WinAPI console functions instead (`AllocConsole`, `WriteConsoleOutputAttributes`, `WriteConsole`, etc.)? Those functions would seem better than a call to a *Linux* console emulator executable from a *Windows* console app through a *Windows* system call.

Comment: This is a whole bunch of code just to output a single ANSI escape sequence...

Comment: Don't write an exe for this. Put it in a script file.

Comment: @KenWhite: Thank you for your comments! `Cygwin's echo` can display ANSI escape sequence. Also, the parameters for `Cygwin's echo` is the same for `Linux's echo`, which makes code-maintenance easier. I will look into the functions that you suggest.

Comment: @user539484: Thank you for your comment. It's only a test before I add other business code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thank you for your comment! However, in that way, the script and the application (to parse data to echo) have to be distributed together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact that shell has *already* returned to the prompt before your colored text ever gets printed. You know that by the fact that the shell *prints a prompt*. It wouldn't do that if it were still waiting for your program to finish running. Prove it to yourself by typing more commands at the prompt and observing that the shell runs them for you.

When you call `WinExec`, you run the program *asynchronously*. That function doesn't wait for the `echo` command to complete before it returns control to your program, and your program doesn't wait for the command to complete, either. Since the shell is only waiting for *your* program, and not any other programs that your program might have started, the shell prints its prompt as soon as *your* program terminates, which evidently occurs before the `echo` command manages to print any output.

To fix this, you need to wait for the `echo` command to terminate before you allow your own program to terminate. `WinExec` doesn't all you to do that, though. That's just as well since it's been deprecated for about 17 years. Instead, use `CreateProcess`. It will return a process handle, and you can pass that process handle to `WaitForSingleObject`, which will block until the process terminates.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments! The combination of `CreateProcess` and `WaitForSingleObject` works! Also, the situation that I encountered is indeed what you described!